# how to map value received for hrSystemDate(.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.2.0) SNMP Object through SNMP protocol to current time and day

Tags: java, snmp

how to map value recieved for  hrSystemDate(.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.2.0)SNMP Object through SNMP protocol to current time and day .I receive values such as 0x07 0xDD 0x06 0x11 0x06 0x37 0x20 0x00 0x2B 0x00 0x00.How to convert this value to current time in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateAndTime is a standard TEXTUAL CONVENTION, so by following its rules, you can extract the data you want,

http://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/using_mibs_in_applns/tcs_dateandtime.html

BTW, an SNMP library/package should have proper method to convert an OCTET STRING object (base type of DateAndTime) to an equivalent data structure so that you don't need to perform the conversion on your own. Have you checked whether the one you use provides such an API?